# COUNT(*) syntax when Select from Left JoinSQL

Tags: sql, count, left-join

I have a LEFT JOIN query

```
SELECT 
    a.id_user,b.id_post, COUNT(a.*) as total_users
FROM 
    posts as b
LEFT JOIN .....
LEFT JOIN .....
WHERE ....
ORDER BY .....
GROUP BY 
    a._id_user
LIMIT 3,10
```

If I use `COUNT(a.*) AS total_users` to retrieve the number of users, but I get an error; what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: `GROUP BY` which is not present in your example

Comment: As written, the code is non-sense.  You have no `FROM` clause.  `a` and `b` are not defined.  `COUNT(a.*)` is generally not accepted syntax.  You have an aggregation function but no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I addded the `FROM`, the question is about how to use `count()` in a left-joined query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax should look more like:

```
SELECT a.?, COUNT(b.?) as total_users
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON . . .
GROUP BY a.?
```

Comment: thank you, but using `GROUP BY` how do I retreive the field in php in this way `$t_users=$row['total_users']`?

Comment: @joe . . . You give it the alias that you want.  Perhaps you should be looking for a tutorial on SQL and using SQL in PHP.

Comment: thank you, but my query is a little complex, I cant find in a tutorial. I updated the query to have an idea, I tried `GROUP BY` but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you need a group by

select a.id_user, b.id_post, count(1)
from.....
group by a.id_user, b.id_post

Answer (score 0):

You can either `Count([some specific field])` or `Count(*)`, but as Gordon Linoff correctly stated, you cannot typically use `Count(alias.*)`

The `Count()` function expects an expression ( a single value ). For each row where the expression is not NULL, that row will be counted. `Count(*)` is a special case returning the number of rows in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Following returns all posts and counts number of users somehow joined to these posts (there is no info about this in your question)

```
SELECT 
    a.id_user,
    b.id_post,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.id_user) as total_users
```